# -productRequest:didReceiveResponse returns empty products array in real store, works in sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store

I recently had an update to an app approved. This versioned added In app purchases. The app **works perfect in sandbox mode** and **Apple did approve both the IAP and the app**, but the in app purchases fails in the app.

I think the crash occurs because the response.products from:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
}
```

returns an empty array and that:

`SKProduct *product = [[products filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate` `predicateWithFormat:@"productIdentifier == %@", _model.packageId]] firstObject];`

returns nil. I can't get the price of the SKProduct. I think that the actual app crash is with these lines since product and payment probably is nil.

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

I read other blog posts that it can take up to 24 hours before IAP becomes available. Is this true? Do I need to worry about bugs regarding the IAP's in my app when it works in sandbox mode and that Apple approved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that this is indeed an Apple problem. I got a response from Apple stating that it can take up to 36 hours before the In App Purchases is available.

I guess this makes it really important to handle the case when

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
}
```

is called, but when response.products is empty. When you try to get the actual product, make sure that you don't get a nil result.

I wish that Apple would not approve and release an update of an app until the IAP was really ready for sale.